# Why does Habitat need to compare User Profile information?

Tags: habitat

In Habitat, the [UserProfileService](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/blob/master/src/Feature/Accounts/code/Services/UserProfileService.cs) class has a method for validating users, which is called on login.

```
public bool ValidateUser(User user)
{
    if (!string.Equals(user.Domain.Name, Context.Site.Domain.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        return false;

    this.SetProfileIfEmpty(user);

    return this.GetUserDefaultProfileId() == user.Profile.ProfileItemId;
}
```

**What is the purpose of the last line?** What does Habitat need to confirm, before considering a user valid? The only thing I can see from following the code is that we try to find an Edit Profile page, but I'm sure I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just ensuring that the user has the default profile, because they are editing/reading/registrating the users with exactly the Default Profile.
You can see in the `Sitecore.Feature.Accounts.Controllers.AccountsController.Register`

```
public ActionResult Register(RegistrationInfo registrationInfo)
{
    if (this.accountRepository.Exists(registrationInfo.Email))
    {
        this.ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(registrationInfo.Email), UserAlreadyExistsError);

        return this.View(registrationInfo);
    }

    try
    {
        // here is the registration with the default profile ID
        this.accountRepository.RegisterUser(registrationInfo.Email, registrationInfo.Password, this.userProfileService.GetUserDefaultProfileId());
        this.contactProfileService?.SetPreferredEmail(registrationInfo.Email);

        var link = this.getRedirectUrlService.GetRedirectUrl(AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated);
        return this.Redirect(link);
    }
    catch (MembershipCreateUserException ex)
    {
        Log.Error($"Can't create user with {registrationInfo.Email}", ex, this);
        this.ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(registrationInfo.Email), ex.Message);

        return this.View(registrationInfo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense. So (in the Habitat world), this login mechanism would block access for any user without the Default Profile?

Comment: @peaks yes because they are only dealing with this Default Profile.

Comment: @peaks if it is the answer for you can you mark it as answer? Or if you have an questions just ask :)